# getenv() Linux/Ubuntu returns NULL

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to get a users home directory using `getenv("$HOME")`, but it is returning NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(void)
{
    char * path;
    path = getenv("$HOME");
    printf ("The current path is: %s",path);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Leave the `$` off the environment variable name. When used in the shell the `$` is not part of the name, but signals the shell that a variable name follows and it should substitute its value.

Answer (score 4):

```
getenv("PATH"); // This is what you really want
```

And, optionally, compile with `-Wall` and end up with something like this. (Tested...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *path;
  path = getenv("PATH");
  if(path)
    printf("The current path is: %s\n", path);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I meant to use `getenv("$HOME"). Using your code I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Compiled as you said. The option is added into Eclipse command. And still receive "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Why do you tell the OP to read out PATH, if the OP wants HOME?

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't that be `getenv("PATH")`?

Comment: Why do you tell the OP to read out PATH, if the OP wants HOME?

Comment: Ah, apologies. I tried it out on my machine with PATH. Should be `getenv("HOME")`.

Answer (score 1):

For the home directory, you could use

```
char* homedir = getenv("HOME");
```

or you could use

```
char* homedir = NULL;
struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
if (pw)
   homedir = pw->pw_dir;
```

For the `PATH` used by `execvp` use `getenv("PATH")`

Answer (score 0):

Since HOME is an environment variable you shouldn't prefix the $ sign to it.

```
char *value,name[20];
scanf("%s",name);
value=getenv(name);
if(value == NULL)
   printf("Not found");
else
   print("value = %s",value);
```

Ensure that you have included unistd.h and all concerned header files.